# PHP Foreach Loop stops several loops into the iteration

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have a function call which returns the following array with nested objects.

```
$customerTransactionsSummary = tickethut_get_red61via_customer_transactions_summary();
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => viaApiTransactionSummary Object
        (
            [orderId] => 4139:2841
            [title] => 4139:DIONVN:110514:174803835IB
            [date] => 2014-05-11 17:48:45
        )

    [1] => viaApiTransactionSummary Object
        (
            [orderId] => 4139:4686
            [title] => 4139:WEB001:310514:164913426OS
            [date] => 2014-05-31 16:50:39
        )

    [2] => viaApiTransactionSummary Object
        (
            [orderId] => 4139:4892
            [title] => 4139:WEB001:020614:171508714RB
            [date] => 2014-06-02 17:15:08
        )

    [3] => viaApiTransactionSummary Object
        (
            [orderId] => 4139:6445
            [title] => 4139:WEB001:160614:155254808MA
            [date] => 2014-06-16 16:05:27
        )
        (...)
```

I am then creating a foreach loop which uses the *orderId* and *title* items and passes them to another function.

```
//fetch the order summary:
foreach ($customerTransactionsSummary as $customerTransactionSummary) { 
    $orderSummary = tickethut_get_red61via_order_summary($customerTransactionSummary->orderId, $customerTransactionSummary->title);
}
```

If I output *$customerTransactionSummary* inside the foreach loop it just stops after 18 iterations.

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($customerTransactionsSummary as $customerTransactionSummary) { 

echo $counter;
$counter++;

$orderSummary = tickethut_get_red61via_order_summary($customerTransactionSummary->orderId, $customerTransactionSummary->title);

}
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: any error when loop stop working ?

Comment: @GokulShinde The rest of the script stop executing. No error messages.

Comment: might be you need to increase execution time then. Try to set max execution time like `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200)`. Here 1200 seconds set means 20 Mins. You can set time as per your requirement.

Comment: @GokulShinde Unfortunately no luck. Interesting to note is that after the foreach loop breaks the rest of the script stops executing.

Comment: on error reporting and see what error it giving `ini_set("display_errors", "1");error_reporting(E_ALL);`. As Gokul said,there might be execution time limit issue

Comment: Finally found it. The API function does a SOAP call and failed and so the loop as well as the rest of the iteration just stopped executing. I wrapped the call inside the function in a try/catch and everything is working now. @GokulShinde

Comment: Its Good you got the reason why it was not working :)

Comment: Thank you for your help @GokulShinde